# Scapy, get raw bytes from parsed field

Tags: python-3.x, networking, field, scapy, packet

I'm trying to extract the raw bytes from a Scapy parsed packet:

This give me the internal representation of data after the dissection:

```
field_value = packet['layer'].field_name
```

field_value returns me type str.

But I need something like:

```
field_hex_val = packet['layer'].field_name.i2m()
```

There is a way to accomplish that without converting all the layer to Raw and then work with the bytes?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what you want precisely, but you can try below code:

```
# Get raw bytes from parsed field 
import datetime
import dpkt
import sys
import struct
import os

from scapy.all import *
counter = 0

filename='dtn4.pcap'

for packet in PcapReader(filename):
    if counter < 1 :
        print(packet)
        print(hexdump(packet))
    counter = counter + 1
```

Hope it will be helpful.